# Hecke operators acting on the Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-functions, hecke-operators

Roughly speaking, my question is the following: Let $\wp(\tau, z)$ be the Weierstrass $\wp$-function, where $\tau \in \mathbf{H}$ and $z \in \mathbf{C}$. If $p$ is a prime number, can we define $T_p\,\wp(\tau, z)$ where $T_p$ is the $p$-th Hecke operator?

---

*More details:* If we evaluate the function $\wp(\tau, z)$ at $N$-torsion points of the lattice $\mathbf{C}/(\mathbf{Z} + \mathbf{Z}\tau)$, we obtain a modular form of level $\Gamma(N)$. Precisely, if we define the function

$$f_{\frac{a}{N}, \frac{b}{N}}(\tau) = \wp \left(\tau, \dfrac{a}{N}\tau + \dfrac{b}{N} \right)$$

then it turns out that $f_{\frac{a}{N}, \frac{b}{N}}$ is a weight $2$ modular form of level $\Gamma(N)$:
$$f_{\frac{a}{N}, \frac{b}{N}}(\tau) \in M_2(\Gamma(N)).$$

**My question is:** Can we define a "Hecke operator" $T_p$ acting on the Weierstrass $\wp$-function such that

$$T_p\,\wp\left(\tau, \dfrac{a}{N}\tau + \dfrac{b}{N} \right) = T_p \,f_{\frac{a}{N}, \frac{b}{N}}?$$

The $T_p$ on the right is the usual $p$-th Hecke operator acting on $M_2(\Gamma(N))$. That is, can we define a function $T_p\,\wp\,(\tau, z)$ such that if we evaluate $T_p\,\wp\,(\tau, z)$ at the $N$-torsion point $z = \frac{a}{N}\tau + \frac{b}{N}$, we recover the usual Hecke operator $T_p$ acting on the modular form $f_{\frac{a}{N}, \frac{b}{N}}$? If so, how would $T_p \, \wp$ be defined?

**What I have thought of so far:** I came across the book "[The Theory of Jacobi Forms](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9162-3)" by Eichler and Zagier where they define Hecke operators on Jacobi forms. But their definition of Hecke operators does not seem to commute with the usual definition of Hecke operators when I specialize the $\wp$ function to torsion points, so I think another definition would be needed. Any insights / references would be appreciated.

Comment: Spelling note: 'Weierstrass', not 'Weierstrauss'.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: What is the Hecke operator on $M_2(\Gamma(N))$ again?

Comment: @reuns I'm pretty sure the Hecke operators are defined the same way as they are for $M_2(\Gamma_1(N))$: for $p$ not dividing $N$, the operator $T_p$ sends $f(\tau)$ to $$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}f\left( \dfrac{\tau+i}{p}\right) + pf(p\tau).$$
And for $p$ dividing $N$, the operator $T_p$ sends $f(\tau)$ to 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}f\left( \dfrac{\tau+i}{p}\right).$$

Comment: That is not the right definition for $\Gamma_1(N)$ either (it will not leave $M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ invariant).